# Creating conditional binomial random selections in R

Tags: r, random, distribution

I have a quick question. This is my function for vector x1: 
    `x1 <- rbinom (100, 1, .5)`

I need to have 3 more vectors, x2, x3, and x4 which look like this too:
    `x2 <- rbinom (100, 1, .5)` 
    `x3 <- rbinom (100, 1, .5)` 
    `x4 <- rbinom (100, 1, .5)`

However, this gives me random distributions. What I want is to have these 4 separate vectors, but they're dependent on each other. I need to get something like this:

```
x1: 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
x2: 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
x3: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
x4: 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

In other words, if there's 1 in x1 on the first spot, there need to be 0s in the first spot in x1, x2, and x3.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What you're describing would yield the following probabilities: x1 50%, x2 25%, x3 12.5%, x4 6.25%, none selected 6.25%. Is that what you are looking for, or do you want an equal probability of selection for each variable?

Comment: I would want an equal probability of selection for each variable

Comment: Why not work with the transpose of the problem?  For each index, randomly choose which of the 4 vectors gets the one?  Note that it's not possible to get p = 0.5 for each vector.  Since there are four vectors, at any given index there's only a one in four chance of being the chosen one.

Comment: @pjs this is clearly multinomial distribution, and I don't think sampling such thing manually is a good approach

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Who said anything about doing it manually?

Comment: @pjs well, sample one position among several, and then loop over how many samples to generate. Sound a lot like manual labor. Please check my answer how to use multinomial for such problem

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, it looks like [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), a.k.a. throwing K-sized dice multiple times. K in your case is equal to 4. Multinomial is natural extension to binomial

There is **R** function to sample from multinomial, for example, 10 samples with equal probability

```
set.seed(12345)
prob <- c(.25, .25, .25, .25)
q <- rmultinom(10, 1, prob)
print(q)
```

To compute density function you could use `dmultinom`. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Multinom.html for details.

Output

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0     1
[2,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1     0
```

and one more piece, probabilities check, should be close to 1/4 each

```
set.seed(12345)
q <- rmultinom(100000, 1, prob)
rowMeans(q)
```

produced

```
[1] 0.25075 0.24964 0.24871 0.25090
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have 4 mutually exclusive options. Then sample from that directly, then you can turn them into essentially dummy variables later.

You can do

```
x <- sample(1:4, 100, replace=T)
x1 <- (x==1)+0
x2 <- (x==2)+0
x3 <- (x==3)+0
x4 <- (x==4)+0
```

This works if you want equal probability of being 1-4 at each draw. This is different than a `rbinom(prob=.5)` for each column.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use 'sample' if I want to size to be a function, rather than an integer? Or do I need to use a different function?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. What "size" are you referring to?

Comment: Can I use a non-integer instead of 100? For example, the number of repetitions would be another expression or a function, and not an integer?

Comment: Yes. Nearly every function in R allows that.